# ¿Como agrego nuevas cajas de texto?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Estaba haciendo un programa donde el usuario haga una lista y se reordene aleatoriamente, ya tengo el algoritmo que hace que se reordene aleatoriamente pero intente un botón que agregue nuevas cajas de texto para que el usuario ponga sus elementos de la lista pero no genera una nueva sino que solo genera una y ya, les dejo el código en JavaScript:

```
let newElement = document.getElementById("newElement")
newElement.addEventListener("click", nuevaCasilla)

lista = []

lista.push("E1")
lista.push("E2")
lista.push("E3")
lista.push("E4")
lista.push("E5")
lista.push("E6")


let rellenar = document.getElementById("rellenar")
rellenar.innerHTML += "<p>" + lista[random(0, lista.length - 1)] + "</p>"

function nuevaCasilla()
{
    let listaUsuario = document.getElementById("listaUsuario") // El id "listaUsuario" es un div
    listaUsuario.innerHTML += '<br /><input type="text" name="caja" id="elementoLista"><br />';
}

function random(min, max)
{
    let resultado;
    resultado = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return resultado;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Listas Random</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Reordena Listas</h1>
    <div id ="listaUsuario">
        <input type="button" value="Nuevo Elemento" id="newElement">
    </div>
    <div id="rellenar"></div>
    <script src="random_list.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Díganme si es necesario otra parte del código para que me puedan ayudar

Comment: Estuve probando tu caso y, en un documento simple, funciona sin problema. ¿No tendrás algún otro id o elemento en tu html que esté haciendo ruido a tu función? podrías mostrarnos como están los tags html donde quieres ejecutar la función

Comment: @AbrahamChan Ya agregué el HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que cuando agregar un nuevo elemento, actualizas todo el contenido del div listaUsuario, provocando que el botón también se  actualice removiendo el event listener. Lo que tienes que hacer es poner el botón fuera del div que actualizarás. Te dejo el ejemplo

```js
let newElement = document.getElementById("newElement")
        newElement.addEventListener("click", nuevaCasilla)

lista = []

lista.push("E1")
lista.push("E2")
lista.push("E3")
lista.push("E4")
lista.push("E5")
lista.push("E6")


let rellenar = document.getElementById("rellenar")
rellenar.innerHTML += "<p>" + lista[random(0, lista.length - 1)] + "</p>"

function nuevaCasilla()
{
    let listaUsuario = document.getElementById("listaUsuario") // El id "listaUsuario" es un div
    listaUsuario.innerHTML += '<br /><input type="text" name="caja" id="elementoLista"><br />';
}

function random(min, max)
{
    let resultado;
    resultado = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return resultado;
}
```

```html
<h1>Reordena Listas</h1>
    <div><input type="button" value="Nuevo Elemento" id="newElement"></div>
    <div id ="listaUsuario"></div>
    <div id="rellenar"></div>
```